# How to disable caching in Ubuntu? Does Ubuntu consume more RAM?

Tags: ram, cache

I just viewed [Hacker News](https://news.ycombinator.com/). There is something mentioned like ["Linux ate my RAM"](http://www.linuxatemyram.com/). How much is it true that linux consumes more RAM.

It will be helpful if someone can provide guide to remove cache of application.

At first my pc use to boot faster than it does now. After installing many programs, I'm facing this problem.

Comment: Nope. It consumes ram less than windows.

Comment: If you are going to use a source at least read it before you post a question. Everything is explained here. http://www.linuxatemyram.com/

Comment: In that website, webmaster has mentioned something like this.
Linux is borrowing unused memory for disk caching.

How to make Ubuntu stop using memory for caching.

Comment: well if you read everything then you should know that this is an awesome feature and not something you should be bothered with. You wont have more lag from low amounts of RAM if you have disk-caching than if you wouldn't. If I remember correct Windows 7 does the same thing...

Comment: Every OS does that my question for now is how to disable disk-caching feature in Ubuntu?

Comment: well it would be stupid to disable it since you don't loose anything by having it. You will loose speed if you disable it, so don't. It's explained in the link you posted, why didn't you read that before you asked this question? and your question doesn't say anywhere that you want to disable it. Please EDIT your question.

Comment: I have edited my question. Hope, I've made you clear.

Comment: It's still the worst idea I've ever heard. Everything will become slow and very very lagy. DON'T DO IT!

Comment: I just want to clear cache of application. Application create cache so that they start quicker next time, isn't it? I just want to clear those application cache?

Comment: I don't know why people downvoted this question. It is quite a good question. **+1** from my side..

Comment: @Habi reading your comments and question, you are mixing several types of caching. Applications cache's aren't the same as memory cache. There are several kind of caches for different kind of uses cases.

Comment: @SauravKumar if it's a good question please explain to us what the question is about. Because right now it's about a million things. He links a source that's an article of how awesome linux is with it's RAM caching (windows 7 does the same thing), and now he says he doesn't want to switch to UBuntu. We don't get what this question is about when a user tells us a million different things. Clarify and edit the question if you understand!

Answer (score 8):

You didn't read the webpage. The link you provided is totally opposite to what you are claiming, so lets bring the information here for you:

> ### What's going on?
>
> Linux is borrowing unused memory for disk caching. *This makes it looks
>   like you are low on memory, but you are not!* **Everything is fine!**
>
> ### Why is it doing this?
>
> **Disk caching makes the system much faster!** *There are no downsides*,
>   except for confusing newbies. It does not take memory away from
>   applications in any way, ever!
>
> ### What if I want to run more applications?
>
> If your applications want more memory, they just take back a chunk
>   that the disk cache borrowed. Disk cache can always be given back to
>   applications immediately! **You are not low on ram!**
>
> ### Do I need more swap?
>
> No, disk caching only borrows the ram that applications don't
>   currently want. It will not use swap. If applications want more
>   memory, they just take it back from the disk cache. They will not
>   start swapping.
>
> ### How do I stop Linux from doing this?
>
> **You can't disable disk caching.** The only reason anyone ever wants to
>   disable disk caching is because they think it takes memory away from
>   their applications, which it doesn't! Disk cache makes applications
>   load faster and run smoother, but it NEVER EVER takes memory away from
>   them! **Therefore, there's absolutely no reason to disable it!**

Now lets go with the boring explanation:

Linux philosophy is that *unused RAM is wasted RAM*, hence it needs to be filled with something useful, which is the *cache*. Caching means that instead of reading files from the old and slow HDD/SSD, it gets loaded in the RAM which is several fold faster than any of them, and at the same time it's translate into a faster programs start up, faster operations with frequently accessed data, a big gain in performance.

> How to disable caching in Ubuntu?

You can't, or more like, **you don't need to**.

> Does Ubuntu consume more RAM?

Against what we are comparing here? Linux and Windows? Ubuntu and other Linux distributions? If is Windows and Linux, Linux has better memory management and smaller memory footprint than Windows. If it's Ubuntu and another distro, is likely that you are trying to compare oranges and apples. You must take into account the Window/Desktop Manager used, kernel version, patches applied, etc.

> How much is it true that linux consumes more RAM.

Again, against what we are comparing?

> It will be helpful if someone can provide guide to remove cache of application.

WHY? The memory is there for any program to use if it's needed immediately they ask for them. The linux kernel doesn't count "cached" memory as "free" memory because is "used", but the cached memory is recoverable and gets destroyed *immediately any application need it*.

> At first my pc use to boot faster than it does now. After installing many programs, I'm facing this problem.

Boot times is extremally subjective, and since you could have installed several programs, is not wonder that your boot times were slower. My boot time cuts around 75% once I removed Mongo DB which reviewed a 300MB database. Just that program added around 2 minutes to my boot time, I disabled to start it at boot time and now my system boots in >1 minute. You should review what programs starts at boot times and disabled them instead. Disabling the cache will not help to make your system boot faster and on the contrary will make your system overall performance worse.

> Application create cache so that they start quicker next time, isn't it? I just want to clear those application cache?

Deppends the application, most applications doesn't use a cache without a very good reason. Browsers for example, has a cache. But this cache is of internet's objects (images, JavaScript, CSS, static content, etc) and the web page loads times are faster in subsequent visits. Other applications use cache's for storing thumbnails, frequently accessed data, etc. Those applications use in-disk caching. That cache isn't loaded in memory until the application starts, and it isn't count as cached memory.

Applications normally can't submit cached pages to the kernel. The memory cache is entirely controlled by the kernel and it dictates what should be cached.

Comment: **+1** for good and complete explanation.  Keep it up.. :)

Comment: Braiam I,m not claiming anything and regarding website, it's true that title in Hackers News confused me. How could I know that? I am just asking this question to be sure not to claim anything. I've not just switched to linux. After knowing about it's memory management and it's performance only I've switched to this.

Comment: @Habi if that's the case, edit your question because that's the only interpretation that it leaves.

Comment: Then help me edit it. My editing it poor Braiam.

Comment: This answer is not very helpful and ignores legitimate issues with disk caching, such as how it slows down your PC. take a moment to write a script that dings at you based on free RAM, and then pay attention to the performance of your applications when it starts dinging... you may notice that your physical RAM use may be between 50-60%, yet feel your PC slow down whenever it starts dinging, this is directly due to disk caching, and I'd personally like to disable it to get more accurate performance from my PC.

Comment: @Tcll err... this is ram caching, not disk caching. Caching content from your disk (or elsewhere) in your ram.

Comment: @Braiam it's the disk caching that's causing the issue, specifically clearing the disk cache that's slowing things down (when using more RAM), the issue is programs that reference files in disk cache when the disk cache is cleared causing slowdowns when addresses need to be reassigned. thanks for trying to guide me, but I do believe I'm correct here. ;)

Comment: @Tcll well, the thing is that for you to be correct, the Linux Kernel developers have to be very wrong. Also, while your observation is correct, the conclusions are wrong. You yourself hint at it "programs that reference files in disk cache when the disk cache is cleared causing slowdowns". They slow down since instead of reading from memory, they need to read from the disk instead. That's not a problem with how the disk cache is implemented, that's a problem when you evict pages from memory, since it has to re-read them from the disk.

Comment: @Braiam I would like to make an additional statement to back my argument, now that I've been able to test, hard clearing the disk cache (`echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches`) actually results in a massive performance boost. programs go from laggy stuttering to snappy smoothness within seconds after clearing the disk cache.

Comment: @Tcll again, for you to be right, a bunch of very [smart people have to be very wrong](https://docs.kernel.org/admin-guide/sysctl/vm.html?highlight=drop_caches). Maybe you should discuss your finding in the kernel mailing list, along with specific performance metrics, to prevent the placebo effect. Note, that if go that route, you should specify what applications are you using, the context around it, etc. Because they would expect the opposite to be true and something very wrong happening on your system.

Answer (score 1):

Disabling disk cache or program cache will only slow down your computer. If you read the whole site that you've linked as source then you would know that is the case and we wouldn't have this discussion.

Hard drive cache and program cache store data in your memory. This makes program startup, usage and opening of files faster. Which it's why you want it.

The misunderstanding here (I think) is that you think that it allocates memory and therefor will limit your amount of RAM available. Which is exactly what it doesn't. It takes zero time to clear the cached RAM and fill it with loaded programs.

So there is no reason to disable this feature, I don't know if it's even possible since it's integrated in the core of Linux and not a feature of Ubuntu.

I just want to make clear cache is a good thing, it speeds up many programs and operations, and it's not just Ubuntu and Linux that have this feature. My Windows 7 gaming computer has the same features.

Having memory on your computer that isn't doing anything is just a waste of hardware it's not something you want, that's also why caching is a good thing.

Comment: Hey, I want to clear cache of application only. I want my OS to be in state of it's first boot. While, everything is new. When there is no cache does it ruin anything? No, it doesn't. Then how can you say it will ruin now?

Comment: @HAbi if an application needs the cached RAM then Linux will clear that cached RAM and the application will be able to use it. cached RAM is an awesome feature that makes your computer FASTER, disabling cache will make your computer SLOWER, it's not a good decision.

Comment: @Habi I updated my answer. you say you don't want to switch to Ubuntu when you found this out, but the truth is that Windows and Mac does the same thing. It's because it's an awesome feature.

Comment: the claim that it takes zero time to clear the cache is entirely untrue, I've written a script that makes my PC ding on low RAM, and it starts dinging when my physical RAM use is at 50-60% rather than the 90% it's configured for... during the time it dings, my PC gets extremely sluggish as it clears the cache, to the point web applications have stopped functioning properly. I'd prefer to disable the cache to make my PC faster (where expected).